# function score with multi-match query

Tags: function, elasticsearch, relevance

I have an elastic query that contains a multi-match query in it..

```
 "multi_match" => [
        "query" => "Will Smith"
        "type" => "best_fields"
        "fields" => [
          "title^10",
          "description^7",
          "keywords",
          "name"
        ]
        "operator" => "and"
      ]
```

I want to Add two function-score query for multi-match query... 
and give a higher weigh to multi-match query with `phrase` type.. and a less weigh to multi-match query that has `best_fields` type...

I mean the documents that has the keyword exactly like what I searched must have higher `_score`

I wrote the query and function_score in a bool and must query... but the result did not changed..

does anyone any idea how to manage my query to get better results?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can show you how I've done something similar. Take a look at below query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "SEARCH TERM HERE",
            "fields": [
              "title^70",
              "description^30",
              "content^20"
            ],
            "type": "phrase",
            "boost": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "SEARCH TERM HERE",
            "fields": [
              "title^30",
              "description^25",
              "content^10"
            ],
            "type": "most_fields",
            "minimum_should_match": "100%",
            "boost": 50
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "SEARCH TERM HERE",
            "fields": [
              "title^25",
              "description^15",
              "content^10"
            ],
            "type": "most_fields",
            "minimum_should_match": "50%",
            "boost": 25
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

First `multi_match` is matching documents only when full search phrase is found and boost entire result with 100.

Second part searches for 100% words from search term. So the order of words does not matter but all of them must appear in searched document. Boost = 50.

Third part searches for 50% match. Means not all words have to be in document to return it in results. Boost = 25.

The `...` part means that I have something more for rest of the results. But it is not needed in each case.

The `boost` values are selected by myself in many tries and could not be good for every single case. You have to remember that behind of relevancy there is a quite complex algorithm. For more info take a look into:

- [What Is Relevance?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html)
- [Theory Behind Relevance Scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html)